# How to mock methods of an activity annotated with @AndroidEntryPoint

Tags: android, testing, mockito, dagger-hilt

I want to create a mock Object of an Activity with annotation @AndroidEntryPoint. After that mock it's methods like
`whenever(activity.getAnalytics()).thenReturn(mockOfAnalytics)`

but it doesn't work for activity annotated by @AndroidEntryPoint, when I remove this annotation it works -  build.tool 4.2.2

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Html::class)
class CallShopViewModelTest {

...

    @Mock
    private lateinit var storefrontAnalytics: StorefrontAnalytics

    @Mock
    private lateinit var storefrontDelegate: StorefrontActivity.StorefrontDelegate

...

    @Test
      fun setShopObject() {
        val mock = Mockito.mock(ShopMenuActivity::class.java)
        whenever(mock.storefrontAnalytics).thenReturn(storefrontAnalytics)
        whenever(mock.storefrontDelegate).thenReturn(storefrontDelegate)
        whenever(mock.getString(ArgumentMatchers.anyInt(), 
               ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenReturn("test")

        objectUnderTest = CallShopViewModel(mock)
        objectUnderTest.setShop(Shop().apply {
            isAcquired = false
            shopId = 100
            twilioPhone = "123"
        })

        Assert.assertFalse(objectUnderTest.mAcquired.get())
        Assert.assertTrue(objectUnderTest.twilioFormattedText.get() != "")
    }
}
```

Activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ShopMenuActivity : StorefrontActivity {

    ....

    val storefrontAnalytics: StorefrontAnalytics
        get() = app.storefrontAnalytics

    val storefrontDelegates: StorefrontDelegates
        get() = app.storefrontDelegates

}
```

So How can I mock this activity and use it's methods?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You better inject `storefrontAnalytics: StorefrontAnalytics` and `val storefrontDelegates: StorefrontDelegates`. Hilt plugin is rewriting your `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotated to a different decorator, this is probably the reason you are getting different results.

If you want to unit test your view model, you should not bring in the activity that hosts it. Provide mocked dependencies directly to the view model. Also why you are providing the activity to the view model constructor? This makes your unit testing excruciatingly painful.

Something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(Html::class)
class CallShopViewModelTest {

...

    @Mock
    private lateinit var storefrontAnalytics: StorefrontAnalytics

    @Mock
    private lateinit var storefrontDelegate: StorefrontActivity.StorefrontDelegate

...

    @Test
      fun setShopObject() {
        val mockStorefrontAnalytics : ... = mock()
        val mockStorefrontDelegate : ... = mock()
        whenever(mockStorefrontAnalytics).thenReturn(storefrontAnalytics)
        whenever(mockStorefrontDelegate).thenReturn(storefrontDelegate)

        objectUnderTest = CallShopViewModel(mockmockStorefrontAnalytics, mockStorefrontDelegate)
        objectUnderTest.setShop(Shop().apply {
            isAcquired = false
            shopId = 100
            twilioPhone = "123"
        })

        Assert.assertFalse(objectUnderTest.mAcquired.get())
        Assert.assertTrue(objectUnderTest.twilioFormattedText.get() != "")
    }
}
```